# The derivative of a square

Tags: calculus

I ws listening to a lecture by Professor Susskind. In a proof of blah blah blah (if you needed to know to answer, I would have put this in physics), he claimed that $2y\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{d(y^2)}{dx}$ This doesn't make intuitive sense to me. Can someone either explain or proof why this is true.

Comment: there is $2$ missing in your equation. it should read $\frac{d(y^2)}{dx} = 2y\frac{dy}{dx}.$  this is just the chain rule.

Comment: In my opinion this question does not merit serious response. The mathematics is completely elementary, hence posting a question about it at this forum seems frivolous to me. Furthermore the question is formulated in an inappropriate arrogant way (blah blah blah).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a pair of parentheses-they are **important**.  The correct claim is that $2y\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{d(y^2)}{dx}$  Now you use the chain rule:  $\dfrac{d(y^2)}{dx}=\dfrac{d(y^2)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

Answer (score 3):

Using the chain rule, we have

$$\frac{dy^2}{dx}=\frac{dy^2}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$$